# Auth login not always saving session data to all pages in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My login method:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Please enter a valid username or password', 'errors/flash_error');
        }
    }
}
```

for some reason won't always show the session info on the page it redirects to. I have a page called `/random` which is routed to:

```
Router::connect('/random', array('controller' => 'submissions', 'action' => 'random'));
```

and when I go to `/random`, it won't show this:

```
<?= $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'); ?>
```

but if I go to any other page, it will..

In SubmissionsController.php in my `beforeFilter()`:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->allow(
            'popular',
            'newest',
            'random',
            'view',
            'category',
    );
    $this->Auth->flash['element'] = 'errors/flash_error';
    $this->Auth->authError = 'Please login or sign up to submit a link.';
}
```

Works above for `popular`, `newest`, `view`, but not `random` or `category`...

Any idea why?

Comment: Try with `<?php echo $this->Auth->user('username'); ?>`. You can also try to print `pr($this->Auth);`. And check whether username exists or not in the 'User' index named array.

Comment: Well I'm using `$this->Session->check('Auth.User.username')` and it's working for all pages except /random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using `flush()` in my default.ctp. This was causing weird session issues. I recommend not using this for anyone who comes across a similar problem.